# Receiving C2660 Error but the call is sending the right number of arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function

I'm trying to send a string `currentline` to a function `letterCounter` that will then alter an array (fullLetterCount.) I get the error

> "C2660: 'letterCounter' : function does not take 3 arguments."

But it **does** need three arguments. I don't know how I've formatted this wrong.

Here is my call for the function letterCounter:

```
 letterCounter(currentline, fullLetterCount, 26);
```

Here is the beggining of the function itself:

```
 void letterCounter(string currentline, int fullLetterCount[], int size){

 }
```

Any ideas about what I've messed upwould be appriciated. (Let me know if more of my code would be helpful.)

Comment: Do you have the function declared (but not defined) elsewhere? I.e. `void letterCounter(...);` (note the semicolon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the function declaration in the header file in which it is declared?

Per the comment, you have it declared as taking no arguments.

You should properly declare it (in a header file) as:

`void letterCounter(string currentline, int fullLetterCount[], int size);`

When your book said you didn't need to name the parameters, it implied that:

`void letterCounter(string, int[], int);`

..., is also correct which it is. However, this is very bad style because when the code is later maintained it will be difficult to know what the parameters actually represent by just looking at the header file.

Comment: Yes. This is how I have it declared: void letterCounter(); outside of main.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. My book said the declaration didn't need arguments, but that fixed it.

Comment: The book said that you did not need to *name* parameters in the declaration, but you still need to list the parameter types